# How to capture error on JDBC connection failure

Tags: streamsets

I am trying to send an email notification whenever a JDBC connection is failing in my streamsets pipeline.

I am able to send email notification when a JDBC query has encountered an error. But not when JDBC connection has encountered an error. Went through a ton of streamsets documentation, but couldnt find an answer to this.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be better off generating a notification based on pipeline states. For more info on Notifications, [click here](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Pipeline_Configuration/Notifications.html#concept_mtn_k4j_rz).

Cheers,
Dash